# Bootstrap 3.3.6, why are my images sideways?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

[image: sideways images]

Can anyone help me understand why my images are coming out rotated? The images themselves are vertically oriented, but they appear sideways in the web page.

[sorry, here is the link](http://www.thedecemberstore.com/)

Comment: Can we see the code?

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't rotate images. There *must* be something in your code that's rotating the images, or the images themselves are rotated.

Comment: I apologize for not including the link, I had fully intended to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on MacOS or iOS then photos that were taken with incorrect orientation data (because your phone had rotation lock enabled for example) then Finder, Lightroom, Apples Photos app and others can automatically detect this and rotate the photos without changing the original file. But a (non Apple) web server or even Windows, won't recognise these properties out of the box, as these non-destructive edits are stored separately.

If your going to run into this a lot I would recommend installing either a bootstrap compatable extension to batch edit photos server side, or run a batch conversion on your computer or mobile device that "physically" rotates your photos and re-saves the change to the file itself. 
This last option is somewhat destructive if you overwrite jpg files as jpg with a compression less than 100% (which is usually the case.)

If you resize photos before uploading to your server anyway the rotation data should already be applied and I advice you to do all edits in one go so the photos only get re-saved once, and not deteriate each time you resave.

One small power tip: you can give very large photos a much higher jpg compression than small photos, but get photos that are, sharper, bigger and with smaller file sizes than if you had prepared a medium downscaled copy that requires a low compression (aka high detail level) setting to still look good. This neat method also makes sure your photo galleries are retina compatable and future proof.

Comment: I apologize for not elaborating further or providing a link, but when you go directly to the image, the image IS vertical, it seems to rotate sideways due to something in the css/html, I've added a link to the page.

Comment: It turns out this IS due to exif data, GIMP was able to fix this automatically, I apologize for the bad question and bad information.  Thank you everyone.